# C# Dynamic method invoke for Task as an Action

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I don't like switch statement. However, I cannot produce any alternative idea to situation as follow. Give me an idea please.

```cs
// Parses MyTask object and routes for execution at a new task
private void PerformTask(MyTask task)
{
    Action<object> taskAction = null;

    // routing
    switch (task.Command)
    {
        case "MethodX":
            taskAction = MethodX;
            break;

        case "MethodY":
            taskAction = MethodY;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

   if (taskAction == null)
        return;

    Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(taskAction, task);
}

private void MethodX(MyTask task)
{
    // do it something
}

private void MethodY(MyTask task)
{
    // do it something different
}

// task holder struct
public struct MyTask
{
    public string Command;
    public int[] Args;
    public int Id;

    public MyTask(string command, int[] args, int id)
    {
        this.Command = command;
        this.Args = args;
        this.Id = id;
    }

}

// Gets next task as a MyTask object and performs it.
// Thread method that is polls task queue
private void DoSomeWorks()
{
   ...
   MyTask task = GetNextTask();
   PerformTask(task);
   ...
}
```

I have some different tasks that should run asynchronously. These are held as MyTask struct.

In **DoSomeWorks** method, the next task is taken from my task queue and then passed to PerformTask method for execution. **PerformTask** method (nitty-gritty) determines that which method will be processed for the task. I just implemented this routing operation with switch case statement. But, I want to do this dynamically. How can I invoke the methods dynamically with command string?

I tried something like this;

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(task.Command);
```

but I cannot convert from MethodInfo to Action. Well, I need help.

**EDIT :**

Thanks for your answers. I have tried both suggestions. This is what i need:

```
private void PerformTask(MyTask task)
{
  MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(task.Command);

  if (methodInfo != null)
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] { task }));
}
```

I don't need Action object anymore. So, I can pass generic param object to Methods. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(task.Command);
if (methodInfo != null)
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => methodInfo.Invoke(this, new []{ task }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a `MethodInfo`, you can try

```
Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), this, methodInfo);
Action act = () => d.DynamicInvoke;
```

or just

```
Action act = d.Invoke;
```

See the example section of [MSDN article on `Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551) for more details.

Comment: is this only static methods? Throws **"Error binding to target method"** error.

Comment: @ozancan: the second argument in `Delegate.CreateDelegate` is an instance where the method has to exist. Maybe you are at the wrong class at that point, and need to specify another object? (For calling a static method, you need to specify `null` as the second parameter; with non-null, it's for instance methods.)